# Connect remotely to SQL Server using python

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, debian, pyodbc, remote-access

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server remotely from my Linux (Debian) machine using Python, I tried everything but nothing has worked

```
import pyodbc 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};'
    'SERVER=192.168.108.186;'
    'PORT=1433;DATABASE=teste;'
    'UID=username;'
    'PWD=my_password;'
    'Trusted_Connection=no;'
    'TrustServerCertificate=yes')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

This gives me:

> pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSPI
> Provider: No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)
> (851968) (SQLDriverConnect)')

The same thing if I use `pymssql`

```
import pymssql

pymssql.connect(server=r'192.168.108.186', user=r'username', password=r'my_password', database=r'teste')
```

and this gives me

> pymssql.OperationalError: (20002, b'DB-Lib error message 20002,
> severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (192.168.108.186)\n
> DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (192.168.108.186)\n')

Comment: Did you know that your first connection string is mixing authentication schemes? `Trusted_Connection=yes;` means to use the Windows Authentication token of the currently executing process (or in this case, the Kerberos token). Whereas `UID=username;PWD=my_password;` means to use SQL Login authentication with a username and password. Choose one of those schemes, probably SQL Login in your case, if you don't have a correctly configured Kerberos client available.

Comment: As to pymssql, it doesn't use ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server, so have you installed and configured FreeTDS? In particular, have you consulted the [freetds.conf file](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/freetdsconf.html) documentation to apply the `encryption`, `check certificate hostname` and `enable tls v1` settings appropriate to the version of the target SQL Server?

Comment: The same problem even after editing my code

Answer (score 0):

for pyodbc.Error:

One of the reasons is an incorrect password. In that case, a Kerberos ticket is not created.

Also, as @AlwaysLearning said `Trusted_Connection=yes`; means to use the Windows Authentication, you have to go with either one of them.

You can see this link as well

https://techjogging.com/access-sqlserver-windows-trusted-connection-linux-python.html

Comment: Same problem, it seems there are some configuration in my SSMS

Comment: @khelilimiliana SSMS is just a client application, the databases are hosted by SQL Server. Just like Outlook is a client application, the mailboxes are hosted by Exchange Server.